Computing Covering Spaces of $A_4$ Cayley Graph
I have a basic computation question regarding working out covering spaces up to isomorphism for Cayley graphs. I'm still getting to grips with the basic definitions so sorry if this question is ill-posed.
Define the group $G=\langle a,b \mid a^3, b^3, (ab)^2\rangle$. This group is isomorphic to $A_4$ by the mapping $$\begin{align*} a\mapsto (2 \ 4 \ 3) \\ b\mapsto (2 \ 1 \ 3) \end{align*}$$ Let $Y$ be the Cayley Graph of $G$. This Cayley graph is the one-skeleton of the boundary of a cuboctahedron, and is shown in the "graph" subsection of this wiki page. For each subgroup $H\prec G$, I want to work out what $Y/H$ is, the quotient of the Cayley graph by the action of $H$.
For normal subgroups, I can do this quickly just by looking at the orbits and drawing it out. However, I'm not sure how to do it well for non-normal subgroups since when I just focus on the orbits and draw it out, I get violations of the path-lifting property.
For example, consider the subgroup $\tilde{H}=\langle a \mid a^3\rangle $. I draw out the Cayley graph and try to map out the orbits by $a$, which gives me $4$ vertices. However, when I connect these vertices together according to the Cayley graph, I get problems with path lifting. I include my attempt in an image below (sorry, I couldn't get it in tikz!),

Where I associated $a$ with the golden $\rangle$ arrows and $b$ with the red $\vert\rangle$  arrows. The problem is that the graph I have drawn doesn't respect the relators. For instance, $(ab)^2$ doesn't lift correctly. How exactly can proceed to fix my $Y/\tilde{H}$ so as to respect path lifting?
